# error when clicking a button on a page, "Expected end of line but found identifier."

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get AppleScript to click on a button on a page, but it's not working. I keep getting the error "Expected end of line but found identifier" just after the 'do'.

Here's the code:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location "https://habitrpg.com/static/front"
end tell
delay 3
tell application "Firefox"
     do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('frontpage-play-button').click();" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Where am I going wrong please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has limited applescript support so those commands won't compile.

Also that javascript was slightly off, should have used `getElementsById`

You could try Safari instead.

e.g,

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://habitrpg.com/static/front"
end tell
delay 5
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('frontpage-play-button').click();" in current tab of front window
end tell
```